# Revert insert into postgres database

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

I failed while creating a script to insert data into a database. I forgot to connect to my database before insert (I was connected into postgres database, in order to create mine), so all my tables are now in the postgres database.

How could I remove all this table ? Is it possible to remove tables by owner, or something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I forgot to connect to my database before insert, so all my tables are now in the postgres database." - How are they in your database if you did not connect in the first place?

Comment: I'll update the post to be more clear, sorry

Comment: do you mean you added tables to the postgres default schema instead of your own created one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DROP OWNED BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html) as long as you are sure that you want to delete all objects owned by that user.

Otherwise you'll have to do it by hand, which should be simple since the database `postgres` is normally empty.

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing to be saved in the schema:

```
drop schema public cascade;
create schema public;
grant all on schema public to public;
```

Replace `public` with the schema name if any.